# flow.js createSlice access generic key

Tags: flowtype, redux-toolkit

Trying to write a declaration for redux toolkit's createSlice. Having trouble creating a declaration that takes in an object that reads one of it's own keys with a function that returns one of the objects keys.

Have tried the following which gives an appropriate return value

```
declare function createSlice<a = {|
    name: string,
    initialState: Object,
    reducers: {[reducerName: string]: () => void}, // can not do $PropertwyType<a> here because flow says a is not defined
|}>(a: a): {
    actions: $ObjMap<$PropertyType<a, 'reducers'>, Function>,
};



const slice = createSlice({
   initialState: {} = {},
   reducers: {
      exists: (state) => {
          state.test = 1 // no flow error
      }

   }
})
slice.exists() //`no error
slice.doesNotExists // flow error.
```

The above properly reads actions, however it doesn't read the state object properly. So i've tried the below approach that does read state properly and show error in reducers but now no longer properly reads actions

```
declare function createSlice<a = {|
    name: string,
    initialState: Object,
    reducers: {[reducerName: string]: () => void},
|}>(b: a & {
    reducers: {[reducerName: string]: ($PropertyType<a, 'initialState'>) => void}
}): {
    actions: $ObjMap<$PropertyType<a, 'reducers'>, Function>,
};

const slice = createSlice({
   initialState: {} = {},
   reducers: {
      exists: (state) => {
          state.test = 1 // flow error. Yay
      }

   }
})
slice.exists() //`no error
slice.doesNotExists // no error
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```js
type AnyAction = { ... };

declare function createSlice<
  State,
  SliceName: string,
  Reducers: { [reducerName: string]: ((State, AnyAction) => void | State) },
>(
  {|
    name: SliceName,
    initialState: State,
    reducers: Reducers,
  |}
): {|
  name: SliceName,
  reducer: (State, AnyAction) => State,
  reducers: Reducers,
  actions: $ObjMapi<Reducers, Function>,
|};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: { member: 'initial' },
  reducers: {
    exists: (state) => {
      state.member = 'test';
      state.nothing = 'beans'; // error
    },
  }
});

slice.actions.exists();
slice.actions.somethingElse(); // error
```

([try](https://flow.org/try/#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))

I dunno how you're gonna get the payload type, though.

Comment: This broadly works for typing the actions, even though flow is complaining. Improvements welcome!

https://cutt.ly/0jAKaA4

The typescript source might be of interest:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/next/src/createSlice.ts